# Lexicographic Product of two Graphs

Tags: graph-theory

How can I prove that the lexicographic product of bipartite graphs is not bipartite? I would appreciate any help on this!

Comment: In particular, it is the product of two graphs.

Comment: You should include in your question how this product is defined.

Answer (score 2):

As per Brandon du Preez's comment, you should include definitions in your question for completeness (especially given the incredible number of graph product definitions.) It would also pay to edit your question with what you've attempted so far.

If you want to show the [lexicographic product](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphLexicographicProduct.html) (see also [graph composition](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/GraphComposition.html)) of bipartite graphs is not *necessarily* bipartite, it would be easy to show via counter-example.

**Hint**: Take the lexicographic product of the simplest bipartite graph you can think of with itself.

If you want to be more adventurous, you can prove the following:

> The lexicographic product of two graphs is bipartite if and only if one factor is $\overline{K_t}$ and the other is bipartite.

You can probably use contradiction for the forward implication. Use the definition for the converse.

Note $\overline{K_t}$ is the complement of the complete graph, i.e. the graph with $t$ independent vertices as its vertex set.